# Is it possible for $\inf \sigma(A+B) < \inf \sigma(A) + \inf \sigma(B)$ for $A,B$ positive?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, c-star-algebras

This question may be trivial. Consider two positive operators $A,B$ in a $C^*$ Algebra.

Is it possible that the lower bound of the spectrum decreases when they are summed?
$$\inf \sigma(A+B) < \inf \sigma(A) + \inf \sigma(B)$$

If all terms are non zero this implies $A, B, A+B$ are invertible and $\|(A+B)^{-1}\|>\|A^{-1}\|+\|B^{-1}\|$ (and would be implied by that inequality in that case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible.  Represent your $C^*$-algebra $\mathcal A$  as  bounded linear operators on Hilbert space $\mathcal H$. Then
$\inf \sigma(A) = \inf_{\|x\|=1} \langle x, A x \rangle$.
Now
$$\inf \sigma(A+B) = \inf_{\|x\|=1} \left(\langle x, A x\rangle + \langle x, B x \rangle\right) \ge \inf_{\|x\|=1} \langle x, A x\rangle + \inf_{\|x|=1} \langle x, B x \rangle = \inf \sigma(A) + \inf \sigma(B)
$$

Comment: Thanks :) (Also you have an $=$ too much at the right)

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo.